# How to create a contiguous nested Vec

Tags: rust

It seems when I create a vec like below, the memory alignment is not done in a way that makes the second vec contiguous with the first. Could you suggest a way to make them contiguous?

```
let v = vec![vec![1,2,3], vec![4,5,6]];

println!("{:p}", &v[0][0]);
println!("{:p}", &v[0][1]);
println!("{:p}", &v[0][2]);
println!("{:p}", &v[1][0]);
println!("{:p}", &v[1][1]);
println!("{:p}", &v[1][2]);
```

```
output:
0x7f6bbc000d20
0x7f6bbc000d24
0x7f6bbc000d28
0x7f6bbc000d40
0x7f6bbc000d44
0x7f6bbc000d48
```

Comment: Store a flatten `Vec` instead of nested?

Comment: You cold use arrays instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have nested yet contiguous `Vec`s. Multiple vectors means multiple discontinuous allocations.

You'll have to flatten your data into one vector, indexing it by `row * num_columns + column` or similar if you want it contiguous. There are plenty of crates implementing contiguous matricies like that.